# questions regarding to vector reserve large memory

Tags: c++, vector

If I reserve large amount of memory for a vector, (it will be filled out with data later on), can the memory reserved be used by others?

for example,

```
vector<double* > vD;
vD.reserve(30000000);  // the number is less than the maximum size of a vector

... ...
for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++)
{
    double * pF = new double;  // will be pushed back to the vector

    ... ...
    vD.push_back(pF);

    delete pF;
}
pF = NULL;
```

The code above just shows the idea. In the real code, double is an self-defined object which contains pointers. When I run the code, I got crashed with info: Free heap block 3bab8 modified at 3bacc after it was freed. The exact memory address(3bab8  and 3bacc ) will change.  when I checked my vector:

```
for _First --- 0x28df0020
    _Last      0x28df0870
    _End       0x3ece3c20
```

For my understanding, the memory reserved for vD should go btw  0x28df0020 and 0x3ece3c20. If I understand this right, then the memory reserved is untouched. Am I right? Then why do I get heap block modified after it was freed? How should I deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: There are too many things wrong with the example code. `pF` lives in the for loop scope only, the last setting to null will fail to compile. `delete`-ing `pF` inside the loop means that the pointer in the vector becomes invalidated (it no longer points to memory). Do you really want/need `std::vector<double*>`?

Answer (score 2):

You're storing pointers to objects, then deleting those objects, thereby invalidating the pointers. The solution is to simply store objects, not pointers to objects.

```
vector<double> vD;
...
double pF;
...
vD.push_back(pF);
```

For cases where you must use pointers (e.g. polymorphic objects), use smart pointers.

```
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> vD;
...
unique_ptr<Base> pF(new Derived);
...
vD.push_back(move(pF));
```

The queries about `reserve` are irrelevant to your problem, but to answer your question: No, once you've reserved space for your vector, others may not use it.

Comment: But vector.push_back(obj) keeps the copy of obj, so I donot need to keep the pointers? Please point out my misunderstanding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1558064: Yes, that is correct. I detect no misunderstanding in that statement.

Comment: sorry, if I understand this right, why do I need to keep the pointers (without delete it)? what am I missing?

Comment: @user1558064: You don't need to keep pointers, except in specific circumstances. I don't know your specific circumstance, since you've replaced your actual object with `double`.  But if it turns out that your circumstances do necessitate storing pointers, then you should store smart pointers (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`). Although I covered this in my answer, so actually, I'm not sure what you're missing.

Comment: @user1558064: The **pointer** will be copied, but you are destroying the **pointed** object. The vector will hold its own copy of a *pointer* to an object that you are deleting.